# Can this be reopened?

Tags: discussion, questions

[How to install Touchégg on Fedora 20](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138371/how-to-install-touch%C3%A9gg-on-fedora-20)

I will add:

- The only RPMs that seem to be available are for Mageia, a fairly distant distro. Needs dependcies from Mageia  (mesagl, which needs Mageia's version of drivers and Mesa) which conflict with the Fedora native ones.
- I haven't found any SRPMs for it so far
- The [instructions to compile it](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/CompileSourceCode) *are for Ubuntu*...
- The above question is one of the top results when searching for varying forms of `touchegg fedora`
- I don't have enough [rep here to vote to reopen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

I also may be close to a answer anyway because I am trying to get it working on Fedora 21, and then will do the same for a Fedora 20 box

I can see why it was closed as it was originally just:

> How do I install [Touchégg](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/) on Fedora 20?

a edit was made after to add what the user had tried - so this still should be a valid question.

Comment: You could either flag this for reopening, or hop into the chat room - there is usually a mod or two monitoring it. In any case, one should be able to write a spec file for this based on the Debian packaging, assuming the build and runtime dependencies are also available on Fedora. Actually, before spending time on this - I suggest you ping the OP (if he is paying attention) and ask him if he still cares. It is such a specialist question it is unclear if anyone else would care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reopened the post. Note that it was quite correctly closed, if you check the revision history, you will see that the original question was simply "How do I install touchegg on Fedora?" and lacked the details that were added later.

Comment: Thanks! I just have to work out one dependcy without breaking things, then I should be able to sort out a nice list of instructions on how to build it :)